# How to use LINQ in C# to query windows local user accounts

Tags: c#, sql, linq, adsi, directoryentry

I wanted to query windows local user accounts from C# using ADSI.
Since WinNt provider is used, Directory SEarcher is not supported.
I am doing the following :

```
DirectoryEntries entries = hostMachineDirectory.Children;
var users = from DirectoryEntry childEntry in hostMachineDirectory.Children
                where (childEntry.Name.StartsWith("User1"))
                select childEntry;
```

Querying with Name is possible. It is not possible to get the description like `childEntry.Description`. It is possible to get the description by using properties `childEntry.Properties["Description"]`.So is it possible to query with  attributes like 'Description' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about AD, but I guess, assuming that `Properties["Description"].Value` returns string, you can try it this way :

```
var users = from DirectoryEntry childEntry in entries
            where ((string)childEntry.Properties["Description"].Value).StartsWith("User1")
            select childEntry;
```

Ok since you confirmed that my assumption was wrong, `Properties["Description"].Value` doesn't always return string, it returns `NULL` sometimes, we need to check for null first before checking with `.StartsWith` or `Contains` or any other string checking operation :

```
var users = from DirectoryEntry childEntry in entries
            where childEntry.Properties["Description"].Value != null &&
                ((string)childEntry.Properties["Description"].Value).StartsWith("User1")
            select childEntry;
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception while trying the above case :'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: check my update, check for null first before checking with `StartsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get string, you should do it this way:

```
DirectoryEntries entries = hostMachineDirectory.Children;
var users = (from DirectoryEntry childEntry in hostMachineDirectory.Children
                where (childEntry.Name.StartsWith("User1"))
                select childEntry).SingleOrDefault<string>();
```

Comment: I am trying to query with a property named "Description" of the local users.But we cannot access the property directly from directory entry like childEntry.Description.It is obtained in the following way : ChildEntry.Properties["Description"]. I wanted to know if there is a way to query with this particular attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work.

```
var users = from DirectoryEntry childEntry in hostMachineDirectory.Children
            where childEntry.SchemaClassName == "User"
            select childEntry;
try { 
    var UserName = users.Single(s => s.Properties["Description"].Value.ToString().StartsWith("Whatever description")).Name;
    Console.WriteLine("User: " + UserName);
}
catch (Exception e) { 
    var err = e.Message;
    Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + err);
}
```